# Capturing Direct3D frames at correct rate

Tags: video, hook, direct3d, avi, frame-rate

I successfully injected a Direct3D application by hooking `d3d9.dll IDirect3DDevice9` methods.

What I'm trying to do is to record an AVI of the application's output.

I can already generate proper AVI files with all frames, using various codecs such as Video1, XVID etc, but my problem is that  *frame rate seems to be incorrect (videos are either too jerky or too fast in comparison with the original application display).*

What i'm doing is basically:

1. If recording video is ON, call `GrabFrame` before the `IDirect3DDevice9::Present` call.
2. `GrabFrame` basically consists of check if we are in "correct time" to take the framebuffer data and add it as video frame. The following is the general code structure:

(Code checks and COM ptr's release are omitted)

```
LARGE_INTEGER now, min_time;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&now);

min_time.QuadPart = _lastFrameTime.QuadPart + (_videoRate * _perfFreq.QuadPart);

if ( (_lastFrameTime.QuadPart == 0) || (now.QuadPart >= min_time.QuadPart) )
{
  CaptureBackBuffer(&pBackBuf);
  LPD3DXBUFFER pD3DXBuf;
  SaveBackBufferToMemDIB(&pD3DXBuf);
  _pAVIVideo->GrabFrame(pD3DXBuf->GetBufferPointer());
  _lastFrameTime.QuadPart = now.QuadPart;
}
```

Where `_perfFreq` is initialized as:

```
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&_perfFreq);
_perfFreq.QuadPart = _perfFreq.QuadPart / 1000;
_lastFrameTime.QuadPart = 0;
```

and `videoRate`is:

```
LONGLONG _videoRate = (LONGLONG) (1000.0/((double)fps));
```

Keep in mind that i'm setting the same rate at AVISTREAMINFO::dwRate member when creating the video stream (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756832(v=vs.85).aspx)

Any help or hint for why I'm getting 'faster' or 'slower' video play?
Thank you very much.